# Syntax when using fscanf to fill a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, file-io, c-strings

I'm currently trying to design a program in C that grabs a player's name and their score from a text file. Both the name array and score array are 2D to help make displaying the high scores easier later down the line. 
Right now I have fscanf set up like this:

```
while(feof(file_p) == 0){

fscanf(file_p,"%s %d\n", name[r][c],score[r][c]);
r++;
}
```

If I remember correctly %s usually means something like

```
  fscanf(file_p,"%s %d\n", name,score);
```

I just don't know how to control which row I put each name into using this format.

**Input**:

```
John 10
Bob 20
Sue 90
```

**Expected Output**:

```
name[0][] = John    score[0][0] = 10
name[1][] = Bob     score[1][0] = 20
name[2][] = Sue     score[2][0] = 30
```

Here's some more code. I messing around with using temporary 1D arrays and strcpy to translate that into my 2D arrays, but I'm unfamiliar with the string library so that didn't work out either.

```c
   void displayHighScores(FILE*fp){
   char name[MAX][MAX]; 
   int i = 0,x = 0,score[MAX][MAX]; 
   char temp_name[MAX];
    int temp_score;
    // Gather scores from the Document
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r"); 
   while (feof(fp) == 0) {
    //gets info from Document and stores in temp variables
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d\n", temp_name,&temp_score); 
   i++; 
   }
   }
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How is the `name` array constructed? What is the output you are getting? Perhaps this is not enough to understand your problem.

Comment: I get compiler errors every time I try to work this out. I'm not sure how %s behaves in a 2D array, especially not when I'm using fscanf(). The name array is defined as a 2D array so char name[MAX][MAX] with MAX being a macro = 100

Comment: Don't use `feof`, control the loop with the return value from `fscanf` which you have ignored but is essential to correct functioning. `while(fscanf(...) == 2) { }` Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: It looks as though you are providing the array definitions to `fscanf`. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem. May I also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to give `fscanf` the addresses of your variables. And for the `%s` you need to give it a char array not a char. `fscanf(file_p,"%s %d\n", &name[r],&score[r][c]);` Though that's a bit of a guess since you have not shown enough code.

Comment: Ouch that looks messy sorry! I'm not sure how to format in the comments. Right now this is pretty theoretical, which is why I didn't post more code. I don't understand how fscanf() works when you want to fill a 2D array, which is fundamental to the rest of my function.

Comment: @user3121023 How would the program know the difference between the row and column inside scanf()?

Comment: Please post the code by *editing the question*, not in comments. You **haven't yet made time** to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how fscanf() work a bit better now! Thank you! I'll try to update you guys on what happens!

Comment: @Watson221 Who or what text suggested `while(feof(file_p) == 0)`?

Comment: Never use `\n` in a scanf format string.  Never use spaces unless you need their special effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are tormenting yourself to no end attempting to coordinate the different data types between multiple arrays syncing names to scores by array index. While that is doable with 2-values, it will wildly spin out of control and become unmanageable. Instead, whenever you need to coordinate multiple values of different types as a single object in C, you should be thinking `struct`.

Here, if you define a simple struct to hole the players name, an array of scores and then a counter for the number of scores stored for that player, you can simply declare an array of struct for the players in your program and read data into each struct for your players. That way the name and as many scores as needed are coordinated in a single `struct` for each player. For example, you could declare your struct similar to:

```
/* if you need a constant, #define them or use an enum */
enum { NSCORES = 10, MAXNAME = 64, NPLAYER = 128, MAXLINE = 256 };

typedef struct {                /* simply struct for a player */
    char name[MAXNAME];         /* using a typedef for convenience */
    int ns, scores[NSCORES];    /* ns tracks the number of scores */
} player_t;
```

(**note:** the `typedef` provides a simple convenience in not having to type `struct` before the name everywhere the struct is used)

You could then read each line into a buffer using `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and then parse the name and the scores for each player from the buffer. You can use a number of methods to split the values in your buffer into the name and as many cores as are provided. In this case, with simple first names, it is probably just as easy to use `sscanf()` and keep an offset of your position in the buffer for reading all remaining scores.

(your other alternative for splitting the line into values are to use a pair of pointers to bracket each value for extraction, use the `strtok()` function (or `strsep()`) to tokenize the line, or a combination of pointers with `strchr()`, `strspn()` and `strcspn()` -- up to you)

You can use `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` to separate value similar to:

```
int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXLINE];          /* buffer to read entire line of input */
    size_t n = 0;               /* counter for number of players read */
    player_t player[NPLAYER] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of players */

    /* while array not full, read each line of input into buf */
    while (n < NPLAYER && fgets (buf, MAXLINE, stdin)) {
        int offset;     /* to keep offset from beginning of buf */
        /* read name from buf, save no. of chars read in offset */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s%n", player[n].name, &offset) == 1) {
            int chars;  /* to track characters consumed for each score */
            /* read score, save no. of chars read */
            while (player[n].ns < NSCORES && sscanf (buf + offset, "%d%n",
                    &player[n].scores[player[n].ns], &chars) == 1) {
                offset += chars;    /* update offset with chars read */
                player[n].ns++;     /* update no. of scores for player */
            }
        }
        if (player[n].ns)       /* if scores stored for player */
            n++;                /* increment player index to next player */
    }
```

(**note:** the characters consumed reading `name` are stored directly in `offset` (as there is no offset at that point), but then the number of character read to convert each digit are stored in `chars` so it can be added to the current `offset` for the next read)

Putting it altogether, a basic example that then outputs the name and score for each player could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* if you need a constant, #define them or use an enum */
enum { NSCORES = 10, MAXNAME = 64, NPLAYER = 128, MAXLINE = 256 };

typedef struct {                /* simply struct for a player */
    char name[MAXNAME];         /* using a typedef for convenience */
    int ns, scores[NSCORES];    /* ns tracks the number of scores */
} player_t;

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXLINE];          /* buffer to read entire line of input */
    size_t n = 0;               /* counter for number of players read */
    player_t player[NPLAYER] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of players */

    /* while array not full, read each line of input into buf */
    while (n < NPLAYER && fgets (buf, MAXLINE, stdin)) {
        int offset;     /* to keep offset from beginning of buf */
        /* read name from buf, save no. of chars read in offset */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s%n", player[n].name, &offset) == 1) {
            int chars;  /* to track characters consumed for each score */
            /* read score, save no. of chars read */
            while (player[n].ns < NSCORES && sscanf (buf + offset, "%d%n",
                    &player[n].scores[player[n].ns], &chars) == 1) {
                offset += chars;    /* update offset with chars read */
                player[n].ns++;     /* update no. of scores for player */
            }
        }
        if (player[n].ns)       /* if scores stored for player */
            n++;                /* increment player index to next player */
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {                /* loop over players */
        printf ("%-10s", player[i].name);           /* output name */
        for (int j = 0; j < player[i].ns; j++)      /* loop over scores */
            printf (j ? ", %d" : "%d", player[i].scores[j]);  /* output scores */
        putchar ('\n');         /* tidy up with newline */
    }

}
```

**Example Input**

To show how this can capture multiple (and a different number of) scores for each player, the input has a different number of scores for each:

```
$ cat dat/players_scores.txt
John 10 11   12   17
Bob 20  30   40   50  60  70
Sue 90 91 92
```

(**note:** all whitespace is ignored since the `"%d"` *conversion specifier* for `sscanf()` ignores leading whitespace)

**Example Use/Output**

The file is simply redirected on `stdin` to the program (the file-handling is left to you, though it simply takes obtaining the filename to read, calling `fopen()` and then validating that the file is open for reading and changing `stdin` in the `fgets()` call to whatever your `FILE*` pointer is)

```
$ ./bin/players_scores < dat/players_scores.txt
John      10, 11, 12, 17
Bob       20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70
Sue       90, 91, 92
```

This looked like where you were heading with your program design for players. It is much better to start off with solid data handling that to charge forward with arrays only to find out it become too unwieldy to manage later prompting a large re-write. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.